# What's the best way of scheduling a task that runs over ten minutes in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

Let's say I have a script that runs for an hour. All it does is sleep for an hour and change something in the Datastore at the end of the hour.

```
def task(keyname):
    time.sleep(3600)
    q = Item.all()
    item = q.filter("keyname = ", "%s" % keyname).get()
    item.value += 1
    item.put()
```

What would be be the best way to accomplish this?

The cron documentation says that "an HTTP request invoked by cron can run for up to 10 minutes, but is subject to the same limits as other HTTP requests." I'm assuming this means cron tasks that run over ten minutes will break.

I looked at the Task Queue documentation, but I don't want to queue these tasks one after another. I want them to happen concurrently.

I was thinking of adding a counter property and running the task every minute instead of sleeping:

```
def task(keyname):
    q = Item.all()
    item = q.filter("keyname = ", "%s" % keyname).get()
    if item.counter == 60:
        item.value += 1
        item.put()
    else:
        item.counter += 1
        item.put()
```

but that accesses the database way too many times.

So, does anyone have a smarter workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cron job hits a handler, and this handler starts a task. This process usually takes less than a second. After that the task can  run for as long as you need it - forever, if necessary. It all depends [on the target of a task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class). 10 minute limitation applies to front-end (F-type) instances only.

And you can run many tasks concurrently if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Background threads running on a manual scaling instance seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean when you say you want "these tasks" to happen concurrently; you've only mentioned a single task.

Regardless, the task queue is the way to do this. You can use the `countdown` argument to the Task constructor to tell it to execute in 3600 seconds.

I usually prefer to use the [`deferred` library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred), which creates tasks dynamically without needing to set up specific handlers:

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
...
deferred.defer(my_task, _countdown=3600)
```

Comment: I was thinking that if I schedule task #1 at minute 0, and schedule task #2 at minute 10, task #1 will finish at minute 60, and task #2 will finish at minute 120 (because it starts after task #1 since it's a queue). I wanted task #1 to finish at minute 60, and task #2 to finish at minute 70.

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

@Soricidae, you're building a cron task.

1. For this you need to have a handler that calls your method **task**.
2. Also, you need to specify a URL route to that handler.
3. Then you need to specify in your cron.yaml a cronjob calling for the **task** method.

*. Additionally I deeply suggest using taskqueues in order for the appengine to solve your load time issues during the cron task.

For example, in my case I have a welcome handler that emails users, checking every 24 hours for new users with more than 1 day that have not yet been welcomed...

So, I've defined the following routes (1 for cronjob, 1 for taskqueue):

```
RedirectRoute('/cronjob-welcome/', handlers.WelcomeCronjobHandler, name='cronjob-welcome', strict_slash=True),
RedirectRoute('/taskqueue-welcome/', handlers.WelcomeHandler, name='taskqueue-welcome', strict_slash=True),
```

Then, I've defined a cronjob handler that once called it goes for the real operations handler as a taskqueue, see:

```
class WelcomeCronjobHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        welcome_url = self.uri_for('taskqueue-welcome')
        taskqueue.add(url=welcome_url, params={
            'offset': 0
        })
```

You can see that this handler asks for welcome_url, which calls the defined handler *taskqueue-welcome* in routes and does the following:

```
class WelcomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    """
    Core Handler for sending users welcome message
    Use with TaskQueue
    """

    @taskqueue_method
    def post(self):
        # ... MY CODE FOR EMAILING USERS ....
        # ... YOUR CODE SHOULD GO IN HERE ...
```

Finally, in order for the cronjob handler to be called every 24 hours, in my cron.yaml file I've added the following, notice the route for *cronjob-welcome*:

```
- description: welcome messaging
  url: /cronjob-welcome/
  schedule: every day 13:00
```

Summarizing, my **cron.yaml** calls every day at 13:00 hours for the **cronjob handler**, which at the same time triggers a **taskqueue handler**, which dispatches a google appengine taskqueue solving **my scheduled task**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation on how cron tasks interact with the taskqueue. However, I don't think the taskqueue is what I need since I'm assuming it's a queue, and it being a queue, it will start on the second task once the first task finishes. What I want is something that can run multiple tasks simultaneously.

Comment: For example, let's say I run two tasks that both take 60 minutes to run. I start the first task at minute 0, and start the second task at minute 10. What I want is for the first task to finish at minute 60 and the second task to finish at minute 70.

I think what I need is to just hit a basic/manual scaling instance with the cron request instead of the taskqueue.

Thank you for teaching me how the cronjob handler works though. I was just in the process of looking that up.